# The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar messing with data and month

Tags: c#

I am using

```
 DateTime MyDateTime1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDOB_panIndTruckAcc_str, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

which is work fine when i am having `txtDOB_panIndTruckAcc_str="12/03/2019"` and when i am using `txtDOB_panIndTruckAcc_str="13/03/2019"` its give me exception.

Looks like there is something wrong in date and month but i am using `MM/dd/yyyy` , which should be fine. not sure why i am getting this error.

Comment: 13 is an invalid month's number and your format string specifies MM for the first two digits

Comment: As other commentators have pointed out `MM` represents a two digit month.  The data input seems to be in the form `dd/MM/yyyy` - See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-mm-custom-format-specifier-1 for a full list of values.

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved.